# How To Extract Audio From Video To Create MP3 file From Video Clip using java

Tags: java, video, mp3

i want to extract audio from a video file through a java program ,is it possible to make a mp3 file or any format so that i can play it in an audio player?if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through pure Java, don't know.

If you run on one platform an option is to launch ffmpeg from java.

Something like this could already work:
ffmpeg -i "myfile.mp4" "myfile.mp3"